# How to combine non-tail recursion + effective and synchronized memoization + bounded stack consumption in Clojure?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, synchronization, stack-overflow, memoization

How can one combine non-tail recursion with synchronized memoization and bounded stack consumption (thus no risk of stack overflow) in Clojure? By synchronized memoization I mean that the memo/cache must be concurrently and efficiently shared among threads.

My specific case is as follows:

```
; g() is non recursive
; i is an integer
; h is a hash with int keywords and vector of ints values
; w is a hash with int keywords and int values
(defn g [i h w]
  (filter
    #(-> (w %)
         (= i))
    (h i)))

; f is recursive, recurses non-trivially (non-tail, multiple times)
; TODO: be memoizable (ideally in a synchronized way, for parallelism)
; TODO: pose no risk stack overflow
(defn f [i h w]
  (if (nil? (h i))
    0
    (let [part_sum
      (map                     ; will change this map to pmap or pvmap
        #(f % h w)
        (g i h))]
      (-> (reduce + part_sum)
          (/ 2)
          (+ 1)))))

; trivial, shown for completeness
(defn ff [i h w]
  (-> (f i h w)
      (- 1)
      (* 2)
      (max 0)))
```

Comment: Regarding memoization: [`memoize`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize) from core lib [uses](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a752736c1a14dce31e2f1cc30adde741328b4b12/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6078) atom under the hood, so it should be thread safe, I believe

Comment: Regarding avoiding stack overflow: that's general question that isn't clojure specific, I'd say. [Here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194646/what-methods-are-there-to-avoid-a-stack-overflow-in-a-recursive-algorithm) you can find some general approaches to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately These questions can be addressed independently:

1. a consistent shared memoize cache
2. non-tail recursive iteration without blowing the stack

For question 1, you need to first decided at what point the cache should be populated. Should it be populated at the time that you start computing the function. Meaning that it should be absolutely guaranteed that each function will only run once, even if a second call is made while the first one is running. Or if you want to allow two calls to the function to happen at the same time and store only one of them into the cache. A slight variation on this is when you simply store the last result returned into the cache.

This last approach is what you get by default if you just call

```
(def memoized-function (memoize function-name))
```

ans it's suficient for almost all cases. If you need the other options then make the funtion you wish to memoize return a `future` rather than the result, and just `deref` the values you get from the cache before you use them.

For option two, the built in `trampoline` function allows you to have constant stack non-tail recursive functions. You change your function to return a value that is not a function (just a normal result) in the base case (when recursion has finished) and to return a function if further recursion is required. then the `trampoline` function "bounces" into the function repeatedly until a value falls out the other side. It looks like this:

```
user> (defn foo-helper [x]
        (let [result 
              (if (pos? x)
                #(foo-helper (dec x))
                x)]
          (println "foo" x)
          result))
#'user/foo-helper
user> (trampoline foo-helper 4)
foo 4
foo 3
foo 2
foo 1
foo 0
0
```

So you can combine the normal caching from Clojure with the normal trampline function invocation without having to worry about "thread safety"